# How to search by sequelize.fn into postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I Have variants `['one', 'two']` into query,
and i have a table:

```
id name variants
0  foo one
1  bar two one
2  foobar one two
```

I want to find into this table these rows that have `one` and `two` in column `variants` in random order

for example:

if i have `one` - It will return all rows

if i have `two` - It will return `2` and `3` rows

if i have `one` and `two` - It will return `2` and `3` rows

Now I join(' ') an array and find by exactly order and use, but i want to find not depending of order:

```
model = await Item.findAndCountAll(
                {
                    where: {name: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('LOWER', sequelize.col('variants')), 'LIKE', '%' + variants + '%')}
                })
```

But it return me

Comment: Seems like you need to use OR with as many `LIKE` conditions as you have input variants

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_split_to_array` and `@>` (contains) operator to match multiple words in any order.

```
const search_term = ['one', 'two']

await Item.findAndCountAll({
    where: Sequelize.where(
        Sequelize.fn('regexp_split_to_array', Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('variants')), '\\s+'),
        '@>',
        search_term
    )
});
```